# Max outdoor range of WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, 802.11n, wireless-bridge, 802.11

So my question is fairly simple, in a normal suburban setting (2 story buildings, no high rises, etc), what is the maximum range you could expect from a WiFi router? Preferably something faster like 802.11 n.

This is a bit of a thought exercise of me sharing my internet connection with my neighbors/friends. I expect I'll never actually do it, but I kind of want to know.

I've seen routers that go up to 600mW and high gain antennas. I was thinking of installing external antennas as each end, I'd have line of sight, but probably don’t want directional antennas on the access point. I would like to be able to connect several homes in several different directions from the access point. Basically I want an idea on what the range would be, so that I can work out how many of my friends in my vicinity I could rope in.

Any recommendations on AP/Antennas?

I've seen the Amped R20000G, are there any other high output APs that I should look at?

Comment: you cant *expect* any range from WiFi

Comment: I've heard good results from this: http://smile.amazon.com/TL-ANT2424B-Directional-Parabolic-connector-resistant/dp/B003CFATOW "in the miles" as it were

Answer (score 1):

About one house.  That's about the range you can expect.  I mean, the neighboring houses.  Anything more and there would be too much normal interference.  Without specifying exact area topography, products used, antenna placement, etc... you really can't depend on a much wider range than that.

Now... if you were going to get serious about this... and you used a high gain external outdoor omni-directional antenna connected to a router, and had that antenna on your roof... and all your friends used wireless cards connected to Cantennas, and they had clear line of sight between those antennas and your antenna... then the (partially) tested theory is up to 8 miles.  There are many stories out there where people have used Cantennas to connect to receivers up to the where the curve of the Earth would make the connection impossible.

Again though... normal equipment... 600 feet.  As far as what specific products would add... all depends on the specific equipment.